# 機会点-Opportunities

Tags: word-choice, translation

Could I translate "Opportunities for Customers" as "お客様との機会点"

I've seen it used in similar ways to the opposite, which is 問題点　("problems")

I was wondering if this is a correct use in the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen such a word as 機会点, but according to Google, 機会点 seems to be the unique term made up by the former president of McDonald's Japan, [Eikō Harada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eik%C5%8D_Harada). Did you see 機会点 in a context related to him?

> その日本マクドナルドＨＤの社長原田泳幸氏は、「課題点」とか「問題点」と言わず、「**機会点**」と言っているそうです。なるほどね・・・ ([source](http://yyamagata18.blog83.fc2.com/blog-entry-546.html))
>
> セールスレポートは昨日までの結果。そして、コールセンターのレポートは、今日からわれわれが取り組むべき課題だ、とも言います。どっちを先に見るべきかというと、コールセンターのレポートです。その課題のところに**機会点**があるわけです。([source](http://keisukeish.exblog.jp/16262099))
>
> "問題点は、**機会点**とよぶ" 日本マクドナルド原田社長 ([source](http://ba-um.tumblr.com/post/26109057245/%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%E7%82%B9%E3%81%AF%E6%A9%9F%E4%BC%9A%E7%82%B9%E3%81%A8%E3%82%88%E3%81%B6))

In general, I don't think 機会点 is recognized by an average Japanese businessperson. Possible translation would be "お客様にとっての機会／チャンス／利点", etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,  it seems I hadn't done my homework very well..

It seems like a logical word to exist but I'll definitely refrain from using it because as you pointed out it is a made-up word that is not widely used after all.

Answer (score 0):

Opportunities for Customers
お客様への機会
It seems to give chance to customer.

お客様との機会 mean the opportunity with customer.

If you have whole sentence, I can choose more appropriate word choice.
Japanese are sensitive.